# creating incremental values for central difference

Tags: python, calculus

The first part of the code works fine and prints off values for `sin` in increments of `.01` radians.  Between `0-25` (degrees) that is 2500 values. The second part of the code is trying to evaluate `sin(x)` using the central difference method, while applying the same incremental steps.

This second part returns just one number. It doesn't generate the incremental list.  This is my first attempt trying to code a differential; what am I doing wrong?

```
#1 evaluation of sin

import numpy as np
import math
def sin(x):
    return math.sin(math.radians(x))

for i in np.arange(0, 25, .01): 
    print sin(i) 

#Evaluation of sin(x) using CDM, which would yield cos

def dfdxsin(f, a, b, n):
    h=float(b-a)/n
    dfdx=0.0
    for i in np.arange(0,25,.01):
        dfdx += (f(a+h)+i)-f((a-h)+i)/(2*h)
    return dfdx

def f(x):
    return math.sin(math.radians(x))

print dfdxsin(f,0,25,2500)
```

Comment: Could you provide a better problem description than *"got myself a little lost"*?

Comment: You mean the paragraph description just above that quote?

Comment: "I am getting just one number back. and can't generate the incremental list"—what are you expecting the output of `dfdxsin` to be? A list or a number?

Comment: I would like for it to be a list.  2500 outputs of cos x between 0-25 with .01 increments.

Comment: Some sample inputs and expected outputs might be helpful for clarifying what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You're just incrementing the float 0.0 by each value you get back. You're going to want to create a list, and append, not add to it.

```
dfdx = []

for i in np.arange(0,25,.01):
    dfdx.append((f(a+h)+i)-f((a-h)+i)/(2*h))
return dfdx
```